# Flutter - Is there a way to disable the expansion of ExpansionTile?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to use an expansion tile and make the expansion capability disabled in few cases... Is it possible to do so? I mean does any of the existing "expansion" widgets cover this thing or not? If not, then is any package available that can help me do this? How should I approach this thing?

Comment: Do you try to view some tree?

Comment: Sorry @rstrelba i don't know what you mean by that

Comment: I mean if you want to build forexample tree in your interface, you can use ExpansionTile for branches and ListTile for leaves

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use IgnorePointer, which prevent children widget from pointer events, and set ignoring to true.

```
IgnorePointer(
  ignoring: true,
  child: ExpansionTile()
)
```

For more information about IgnorePointer, check the [docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/IgnorePointer-class.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot... the ignore pointer definitely is the solution

Comment: that's not a solution. I need to detect something when I click on the ExpansionTitle. If it's true I active something but not the ExpansionTitle. Having this IgnorePointer it doesn't work

Comment: @Dani Although I'm a year and 3 months late with an answer. You can always wrap the IgnorePointer with a GestureDetector.